# How can I generate a list of all possible IPs from a CIDR list in Python and assign another column to it from the original list?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a csv file that contains a column of CIDR IPs and a column that has the location of where that IP is being used, like this:

```
   | CIDR         | Location   |
   | ------------ | ---------- |
   | x.x.x.x/24   | OFFICE     |
   | x.x.x.x/24   | DATACENTER |
   | x.x.x.x/25   | DATACENTER |
   | x.x.x.x/26   | DATACENTER |
```

And the csv continues on,
I want to create a new csv file from this that would expand the CIDR to all its possible IPs, but still have the proper location tied to it.

```
  | IPs       | Location |
  | --------  | -------  |
  | y.y.y.y   | OFFICE   |
  | y.y.y.y   | OFFICE   |
  | y.y.y.y   | OFFICE   |
  | y.y.y.y   | OFFICE   |
  | y.y.y.y   | OFFICE   |
```

and so on

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it is using netaddr module & apply to CIDR column

```
>>> import netaddr
>>> data = {
    'CIDR': ['10.0.0.0/29', '10.1.2.0/30',  '192.168.1.0/29', '172.16.0.0/29'],
    'Location': [  'OFFICE',  'DATACENTER',  'DATACENTER', 'DATACENTER']}
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)
>>> pd.concat([df,df.CIDR.apply(netaddr.IPNetwork).explode().rename('IP')], axis=1)


    CIDR            Location    IP
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.0
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.1
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.2
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.3
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.4
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.5
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.6
0   10.0.0.0/29     OFFICE      10.0.0.7
1   10.1.2.0/30     DATACENTER  10.1.2.0
1   10.1.2.0/30     DATACENTER  10.1.2.1
1   10.1.2.0/30     DATACENTER  10.1.2.2
1   10.1.2.0/30     DATACENTER  10.1.2.3
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.0
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.1
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.2
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.3
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.4
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.5
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.6
2   192.168.1.0/29  DATACENTER  192.168.1.7
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.0
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.1
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.2
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.3
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.4
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.5
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.6
3   172.16.0.0/29   DATACENTER  172.16.0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your DataFrame has **valid** CIDR you can combine [`ipaddress.IPv4Network`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html#ipaddress.IPv4Network) and [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
import ipaddress
df2 = (df.assign(CIDR=df['CIDR'].map(lambda x: list(ipaddress.IPv4Network(x))))
         .explode('CIDR')
      )
```

example input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'CIDR': ['192.168.1.0/24', '10.0.0.0/24'],
                   'Location': ['OFFICE', 'DATACENTER']})
```

output:

```
           CIDR    Location
0   192.168.1.0      OFFICE
0   192.168.1.1      OFFICE
0   192.168.1.2      OFFICE
0   192.168.1.3      OFFICE
0   192.168.1.4      OFFICE
..          ...         ...
1    10.0.0.251  DATACENTER
1    10.0.0.252  DATACENTER
1    10.0.0.253  DATACENTER
1    10.0.0.254  DATACENTER
1    10.0.0.255  DATACENTER

[512 rows x 2 columns]
```